# Detect focus change in parent window(s) of treeview

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview, focus

Ok this seems pretty straightforward but how to do this? The edit controls send an `EN_KILLFOCUS` message, but I can't really find something similar for the treeview control.

Exact situation: Parent window (a property sheet page) creates a custom control that has a treeview on it (just the plain old SysTreeView32).

My best idea until now is to subclass the control that holds the treeview and the treeview itself, but thats no joy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you are looking for is [NM_KILLFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773479%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Awesome, works beautifully! I knew this could be tackled ridiculously easy :) Thanks!